# how to select rows for combination of column values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table `search_settings`  with content as following:

```
    +-----------+-------------+----------+
    | entity_id | language_id | query_id |
    +-----------+-------------+----------+
    |         2 |          71 |      141 |
    |         3 |          72 |      141 |
    |         4 |          73 |      141 |
    |         4 |          74 |      142 |
    |         4 |          75 |      142 |
    +-----------+-------------+----------+
```

How to select unique `query_id`s for which, there are existing entries with language_id=71 and language_id=72 and language_id=73 ?

For example i need `query_id = 142` row if `language_id=74` and `language_id=75`, but if `language_id=999` and `language_id=75` it should return nothing ?
is it possible ?

Comment: Can you Show the result as table. I think the result is unclear in this Kind of description

Comment: should the result be 141 in your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group by` with `having` to check if a query_id has all the required language_id's associated with it.

```
select query_id
from tablename
group by query_id
having sum(case when language_id in (74,75) then 1 else -1 end) = 2
```

Comment: thanks thats almost what i need!  but how to make it match if _only_ 74 and 75 languaged_ids are present (if 76 also exists for this query_id it should return nothing)?

Comment: see the edited answer. use `-1`  so the sum would be less than 2 if there is any other language_id for a given query_id.